Using libgpiod version 2.1.x, how to convert gpiod::timestamp to std::chrono::nanoseconds?
I'm using libgpiod C++ version 2.1.x to get multiple line changes:
Code from github example files:
  auto request =
        ::gpiod::chip(chip_path)
            .prepare_request()
            .set_consumer("qedged_io")
            .add_line_settings(
                line_offsets,
                gpiod::line_settings()
                    .set_direction(
                        gpiod::line::direction::INPUT)
                    .set_edge_detection(
                        gpiod::line::edge::BOTH))
            .do_request();

    gpiod::edge_event_buffer buffer;

    while (true)
    {
        /* Blocks until at leat one event available */
        request.read_edge_events(buffer);

        for (const auto &event : buffer)
        {
            std::cout << "offset: " << event.line_offset()
                      << "  event #" << event.global_seqno()
                      << "  line event #" << event.line_seqno()
                      << ::std::endl;
           
             auto ts = event.timestamp_ns();

             std::chrono::nanoseconds ns = ts.?????; <<== How to convert gpiod::timestamp to std::chrono::nanoseconds, considering the real time clock?

        }
    }

After getting the event I need to get the timestamp in std::chrono::nanoseconds to be used in another function...
How to convert gpiod::timestamp received from event timestamp_ns() to std::chrono::nanoseconds ?

std::chrono::nanoseconds doesn't store timestamps.  It stores durations.  A duration measures the time between two timestamps.  Are you looking for the duration between this timestamp and the Unix epoch?

Yes, exactly. I need the exact moment that the line was read, referenced by Unix epoch.

If you want the time the edge occurred, consider using the REALTIME event clock option rather than the default MONOTONIC.  See line_settings.set_event_clock().  Or use timestamp.to_time_point_realtime().

According to the documentation, you can get a nanosecond count since Unix epoch with the member function ns()
std::chrono::nanoseconds ns( ts.ns() );

